# FreeForm: Accessing a fields customAttributes

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace

Is it possible to access `customAttributes` on a FreeForm field?

Currently attempting to do this via:

```
{% for row in form %}
  {% for field in row %}
    {{ dump(field.customAttributes) }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Where form is a FreeForm object.

Currently I'm getting an error that indicates that attribute does not exist or I can't access it.

Comment: > *Sorry this isn't a comment, i don't have enough rep to comment yet.* I'm having this issue right now. I need to show/hide a field's parent "row" based on another fields value (the rules in the conditional editor aren't thorough enough in this case). I've added an input attribute to a field that I want to control the row of but `field.inputAttributes` or `field.customAttributes.inputAttributes` isn't available like the docs [make it seem like it would be](http://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v2/template-objects/field.html#prop-custom-attributes). Errors I'm seeing are Neither the property

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to access the properties individually like this, assuming you've set them on the Form object:

```
{{ form.customAttributes.rowClass }}
{{ form.customAttributes.columnClass }}
{{ form.customAttributes.inputClass }}
Etc...
```

https://solspace.com/craft/freeform/docs/form/#prop-custom-attributes

Comment: Roger that, what about properties set on the field object?

Comment: Can you think of a use-case where you would apply attributes to a field but then render those manually? Or apply it to the field object instead of form object?