# FreeForm fields: Need access to customAttributes

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace

Pretty much a duplicate of [FreeForm: Accessing a fields customAttributes](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/29118/freeform-accessing-a-fields-customattributes) but to answer Solspace's comment "Can you think of a use-case where you would apply attributes to a field but then render those manually?", yes I can.

My current project has Company entries and Equipment entries. Each user belongs to a single Company.

When a user fills out a form with a select field where source=entries and target=Equipment, I don't want the user to see all equipment in the system. Only equipment belonging to user's company.

I thought a clever idea would be to add field class "filterEquipment". When rendering my form

- if field.type=select and field class contains "filterEquipment" I want to loop through field options and only display equipment that belongs to user's company
- else render select field as normal

I'm open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suggestion from Freeform support:

> The only way you might be able to achieve this would be if you used a regular Text field (inside of Composer), and then override the formatting template to manually render the field as a select dropdown and populate the options dynamically. Actual fields with options such as Select fields need to have all of their options pre-defined inside Composer, which is why it wouldn't work otherwise. Using the element populators could almost get you there, but it doesn't allow dynamic filtering like what you'd need.